# gevent and thread performance compare?

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent

i write a test case to compare thread and gevent's performance,
using multithread to do a task like:

```
import time
import threading

def sync_task():
    #do something
    time.sleep(1)

def multi_thread_run():
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=sync_task)
        t.start()
    end = time.time()
    print("multi thread task executed in %f second"%(end-start))
```

print:

```
multi thread task executed in 0.002425 second
```

however, using gevent replace thread do same task:

```
import gevent
def async_task():
    #do something
    gevent.sleep(1)

def async_run():
    start = time.time()
    coroutins = []

    for i in range(10):
        coroutins.append(gevent.spawn(async_task))
    gevent.joinall(coroutins)

    end = time.time()
    print("async task executed in %f second"%(end-start))
```

print:

```
async task executed in 1.002012 second
```

in many blog post I see coroutine is more effective than mutilthread, in this case, how to explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't `join` your `Thread` - it means that program doesn't wait for thread to finish executing, and instead ends almost immediatelly.